# Android opengl: apply texture to square

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I've been following along with the android opengl tutorial on the official website found here:

developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/

The full project is here:

https://www.javatips.net/api/opengl-master/HelloOpenGLES32/app/src/main/java/edu/cs4730/helloopengles32/MyGLRenderer.java

How can i modify this code so that I can use a Bitmap as a texture with the Square class? Is this tutorial expounded upon anywhere?

Thanks.

Comment: The code in the tutorial I linked

Comment: Apologies. Here is a link for the complete project:https://www.javatips.net/api/opengl-master/HelloOpenGLES32/app/src/main/java/edu/cs4730/helloopengles32/MyGLSurfaceView.java#